# Swap a second child's content by using CSS

Tags: css

```
.swap:hover span{
    display: none;
}

.swap:hover:before {
    content: attr(rel);
}

<div class = "first">
    <div class = "second"></div>
    <div class = "third swap" rel="text"><span>...</span></div>
</div>
```

I currently use this code. It works well when mouse hover third.

```
<div class = "first swap">
    <div class = "second"></div>
    <div class = "third" rel="text"><span>...</span></div>
</div>
```

I want to edit code like this. I need to replace third content when mouse hover first.
How can I edit CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this..if I understand you correctly.

```
.swap:hover .third span {
  display: none;
}
.swap:hover .third:before {
  content: attr(rel);
}
```

```css
.first {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.second {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.third {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first swap">
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third" rel="New content"><span>Old Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```